# If $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are $+/- 1$, then $\text{det}(B)$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, determinant

My approach is this subtraction of last row, say $r_n$, one by one from other rows then the entry in each row will be $-2$, $+2$ or $0$.Taking $2$ common from each row except the last row we will have $2^{n-1}$ × something, thus $\text{det}(B)$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.
Is this correct?

Comment: I just want to know whether my approach is correct or not. Is it correct?

Comment: What is the meaning of correct? If you would submit this, I would give you $3$ of $10$ points. Somehow a good start, but all details missing (what means taking 2 common?) . For these details, see the duplicates.

Comment: the nicest approach is probably to look at Smith Normal Form, then look at what happens to rank under the ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z_2 \cong \mathbb F_2$ (i.e. rank goes from $r$ to $1$ implying that all elements of $D$ in Smith Normal Form are multiples of 2 except the top left corner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt looks good to me, but for completeness, I think you should explain why that "something" (obtained after pulling out a factor $2$ from each row) is an integer.